# VSCode not running kernel for large Jupyter notebook file (showing as html only)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have this relatively large Jupyter notebook file that I've been working with. This morning when I opened it, VSCode only shows the html text, but not the notebook kernel with executable cells. Like this:

```
{
 "metadata": {
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.8.5-final"
  },
```

I've created other files in the same directory and VSCode correctly opens and renders them as Jupyter Notebooks, so I'm not sure what could be the problem with this one.
I received some warning yesterday about the file size and today after I changed the file name it stopped working. I get not errors though, just the kernel not launching.

Any ideas of what could be the issue here?

Comment: What are the details of Jupyter that you said does not work? Could you show us relevant screenshots? Also, it is recommended that you reinstall the Jupyter-supported kernel "ipykernel" in the current environment.

Comment: Same issue here. There was a warning which I ignored, but how to reset the behaviornow?